# How to add delete link for imported content type

Tags: 7, nodes, features

For the content type which is imported by feature, there is no delete link for it, but we can delete them by going to the url `/admin/structure/types/manage/YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE/delete`

My question is how to make the delete link also available for the imported content type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I am agains editing db directly, the simplest solution would be do edit table in your database.

find 'node_type' table and under 'custom', for your content type, change 0 to 1.